# Checkbox checked state change when visibility is set to false

Tags: asp.net, viewstate

I am having some trouble understanding the impact of setting checkbox visibility on the checked state at various stages in the page life cycle.

Given below is a sample code for a dynamically created checkbox.

```
    protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnInit(e);

        check = new CheckBox();
        check.AutoPostBack = true;
        check.Text = "checkbox1";
        check.ToolTip = "tooltip for checkbox1";
        check.CheckedChanged += new EventHandler(check_CheckedChanged);  

        this.Form.Controls.Add(check);
        Button btn = new Button();
        btn.Text = "click me";
        btn.Click += new EventHandler(btn_Click);
        this.Form.Controls.Add(btn);

    }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            check.Checked = true;
            check.Text = "text reassigned.";
            check.ToolTip = "tooltip reassigned";
        }

    }

    protected override void OnPreRenderComplete(EventArgs e)
    {            
        base.OnPreRenderComplete(e);
        check.Visible = false;
    }
```

The issue here is, when a postback occurs (I click on the button), then I notice in the Page_load event, the checkbox maintains the viewstate of the tooltip and text. However the checked state is changed to false and it fires a CheckedChanged event. Why is the behavior so?

Also, if I set the visibility of the checkbox in either PageLoad() or the OnPreRender() event, the checked state of the checkbox is maintained across postbacks and does not fire a CheckedChanged event.

I'm just curious as to what happens differently when the visibility is changed in the OnPreRenderComplete event so as to have the checkbox default to an unchecked state.

Comment: What's the use of that? Is it curiosity? The page life cycle is a known mystery.

Answer (score 1):

Well I have marked my last answer for deletion, as I didn't understand the question properly.

Well the things you are doing are:

1. You added the checkbox at runtime in Init event on server side.
2. Then in page load you set its value to true in the Not Post Back check.
3. Then you set its visibility to false in OnPreRenderComplete event

When you set the visibility to false on server side, the control is not generated on client side (you can check it by viewing the page source), as control is not created on client side so when you post back the page, the checkbox is created in page init and as it was not on client side so dot net doesn't know about its last value, so you get false for the check box.

If you need to check it more further, change your OnPreRenderComplete event as:

```
protected override void OnPreRenderComplete(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPreRenderComplete(e);
        //check.Visible = false;
        check.Style.Add("display", "none");
    }
```

By above line, the style is being added to the control, so the control is generated on client side but is not visible and you will get its value during the post back.

Comment: wow, I have voted 1 for your question, now I realized that the text and tooltip are being retained but not the checked value. :$

Comment: When I decoded the viewstate of the page, I find text and tooltip values present in it and flase for checked value, this is a very strange behavior.

Comment: There is one more twist that I have come across, in Init event I am assigning a new ID to the checkbox everytime, like:                check.ID = "chkMyCheckBox" + DateTime.Now.Second.ToString();           If I am doing it like this, checkbox is retaining its checked value and also the CheckedChanged event is not firing.